# How to get count of dynamic 'div's' nested inside a each 'td' tag?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have table which have several `<td>` tags,  again these tag have nested 
 `<div>` tag. But the number of `<div>` are dynamic. Means, for each `<td>` tag number of `<div>` are different.

I wanted to find the total number of `<div>` inside a `<td>` and iterate them to grab each div's value.

I've tried using below xpath, but I'm not sure how can I get the count of `<div>`'s for loop through them.

```
for(int i=1;i<=NoOfDivs;i++) 
{
    WebElement NestedDivs= driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table[4]/tbody/
    tr[3]/td[2]/div["+i+"]"));
}
```

Webpage **HTML** is given in the below snap:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below method template to get the number of div.

```
public static int get_div_count_in_table(){
    String _xpath = "//table//td[td_no]/div" ; 
    List<WebElement> _divs = driver.findElements(By.xpath(_xpath)); 
    int NoOfDivs = _divs.size(); 
    return NoOfDivs; 
}
```

You might alter the code snippet as per your requirement, but the logic mostly 
will remain the same.

I have tried a similar problem in this page, to get the list of divs and it is returning the expected. Please see below the page and xpath.

[image]

[image]

The xpath returns 10 as the size. Check this and let us know if you are able to follow.

Comment: I tried this but it returns zero as _divs.size()

Comment: I have updated the answer itself to address your query as it needed to attach images. Hope this helps.

Comment: Strange,,i just removed all and re-write that piece  of code  & it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are locating the correct table. Based on information provide by you. Please refer the below code snippet to find all the `<div>` and iterate through.

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[4]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div"));
int totalDivs = allElements.size();
System.out.println("total divs :"+totalDivs)

for(WebElement element : allElements){
    System.out.println("Value :"+element.getText());
}
```